# How to exclude particular DIV of HTMl with id/class, Header and footer sections while crawling web pages using storm-crawler?

Tags: html, jsoup, apache-tika, text-extraction, stormcrawler

I'm trying to crawl the website with html pages with header and footer which are common for all my pages and 2 seperate DIVs with ids. I want to store the content of div with id=firstSection, id=secondSection data in my ES. But entire html data with header and footer is storing into my ES. Is there any way to crawl particular DIV id or Can i exclude any particular DIV content not to store to my ES?

**Note**: I tried to add the class/id of div in Exclude tags, but it didn't work.

I'm using Storm Crawler 1.17 & ES-7.6

Following is my config and htmls

### **crawler-conf.yaml**

```
# text extraction for JSoupParserBolt
  textextractor.include.pattern:
   - DIV[id="maincontent"]
   - DIV[itemprop="articleBody"]
   - ARTICLE
   - DIV[id="block-edu-bootstrap-subtheme-content" class="block block-system block-system-main-block"]
   - MAIN[role="main"]
   - DIV[id="content--news"]
   - DIV[id="content--person"]
   - ARTICLE[class="node container node--type-facility facility-full node-101895 node--promoted node--view-mode-full py-5"]
   - ARTICLE[class="node container node--type-spotlight spotlight-full node-90543 node--promoted node--view-mode-full py-5"]
   - DIV[class="field field--name-field-content field--type-entity-reference-revisions field--label-hidden field__items"]
   - BODY


  textextractor.exclude.tags:
   - STYLE
   - SCRIPT
   - HEADER[class="fixed-header"]
   - FOOTER[class="fixed-footer"]
```

and sample html file i used

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Implement Sticky Header and Footer with CSS</title>
<style>
/* Add some padding on document's body to prevent the content
    to go underneath the header and footer */
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}


.fixed-header, .fixed-footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #333;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #fff;
}


.fixed-header {
    top: 0;
}


.fixed-footer {
    bottom: 0;
}


.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center the DIV horizontally */
}


.welcome-box {
    background: #cccccc;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
}


nav a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fixed-header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <a href="#">Home</a> <a href="#">About</a> <a href="#">Products</a>
                <a href="#">Services</a> <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="firstSection">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="welcome-box">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <p>Hi, welcome to our website.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="welcome-box">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="secondSection">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="welcome-box">
                <h1>Welcome2</h1>
                <p>Hi, welcome to our second section.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="welcome-box">
                <h1>Second section</h1>
                <p>Hi, welcome to our second section.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div id="thirdSection">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="welcome-box">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <p>Dont crawl this section.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="welcome-box">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <p>Dont crawl this section</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-footer">
        <div class="container">Copyright &copy; 2020 Your Company</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would be useful  if you could include the jsoup java code here

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the exclusion doesn't work (and don't have the time to test on the example you provided) but you could configure the XPathFilter to extract the elements you are interested in under a specific key in the metadata and then configure the indexer to store the content of this key as a field in ES.

See [parse filter config from archetype](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/resources/parsefilters.json) for an example of how to set up the XPathFilter.

Comment: Thanks @julien-nioche for quick replay.

As you said, we are able to extract the metadata from HTML using XPathFilter, but in my case content comes dynamically.
we see only exclude by tags in configuration. Is there any way to exclude content by pattern?(because header and footer is common across all pages)

Comment: The exclusion works only with tags, regardless of the attributes of the elements.
if the content is dynamic, why not use the Selenium protocol instead. See http://digitalpebble.blogspot.com/2017/04/crawl-dynamic-content-with-selenium-and.html